# Vyatta Remote Access VPN firewall (PPTP)

Tags: linux, vpn, firewall, pptp, vyatta

I am using Vyatta Remote Access VPN (PPTP) and NAT for proxy.
When pc-A and pc-B are connected to VPN, pc-A ipaddress is 192.168.10.10 and pc-B is 192.168.10.11.

```
[pc-A:192.168.10.10]--internet(VPN)--[Vyatta]--internet(VPN)--[pc-B:192.168.10.11]
```

pc-A is visible from pc-B.(can ping each other.) 
But I don't want to connect pc-A and pc-B for security reason.How do I configure this? (firewall?)

Comment: With centos6,pptpd,and iptables, i could make isolate PCs. 
iptables -I FORWARD  -d 192.168.10.0/24 -s 192.168.10.0/24 -j DROP